# How to add wallpapers to iOS 7?

Tags: ios

How can I add wallpapers to iOS 7 without adding them to Photos.app ?

Is there a way to add wallpapers to native iOS wallpapers?

Comment: Short answer is no, at least not without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 4):

## No :(

The list of Apple wallpapers in **Settings** → **Wallpapers & Brightness** → **Choose Wallpaper** → **Apple Wallpaper** → **Dynamic** or **Stills** is not customisable by the user, without jailbreaking.

If you want a separate list of wallpapers, you can create an album in the Photos app, add your wallpapers to that album, then open that wallpaper in the **Choose Wallpaper** → **Photos** list.

Answer (score 3):

No. The only (non-jailbreak) way to add wallpaper is by selecting it from a photo album or Photostream.

However, once you have chosen the wallpaper and/or lock screen, you can delete the image from your Photo collection.